# Call to a member function query() on a non-object Magento

Tags: php, magento, mysqli

I'm trying to run an `insert` query on my site but I get the `Call to a member function query() on a non-object` error everytime I try to run the script. I've tried deleting the first value (NULL) since thats the id and it's auto increment but that didn't help either.

**Connect**

```
class database{
    function connect(){
        Define ('HOST'    , 'host'  );
        Define ('USERNAME', 'username'  );
        Define ('PASSWORD', 'password'  );
        Define ('DATABASE', 'database'  );

        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

        if($con->connect_errno){
            echo "Er kon geen verbinding worden gemaakt met de server <br>" .$con->connect_errno();
            exit();
        }
    }
}

$database = new Database();
$database->Connect();
```

**Insert**

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$id = 2074;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO  cataloginventory_stock_item(
     item_id ,
     product_id ,
     stock_id ,
     qty ,
     min_qty
)VALUES (
     NULL ,  '$id',  '1',  '999.0000'
)";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: remove $ sign from $mysqli->query

Comment: Since you're using the procedure method, you should use `mysqli_query`

Comment: $mysqli->query($sql); will be mysqli_query($sql);

Comment: @OfirBaruch please up-vote the answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are merging object oriented approach to procedural approach:-

Your insert page code have no relation with connect, So you need to this:-

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)) ;
```

If you want to use object oriented approach then in your insert page do like this:-

```
$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->Connect();
```

and then  `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: I've tried both approaches but the error still won't go away.. When I `var_dump` `$result` at the procedural approach it returns `NULL`

Comment: sorry my mistake.please check edited one. check the procedural one.

Comment: i've added the `$con` to the query myself but there is no error returned while the variable is still empty

Comment: no error? how's it's possible? if any error is there then it will generate error definitely otherwise check insertion will happen?

Comment: no error, the result var is empty and the row isn't inserted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77705/discussion-between-anant-kumar-singh-and-oryna).